# Downloading .csv from SSRS need to avoid scientific notation format

Tags: sql, excel, ssrs-2008

Have an issue where when a report is downloaded, a field that has over 15 digits is converted to scientific notation instead of displaying the full digits (i.e. 672000000000000 = 6.72×10 to the 14th degree). I know this is an excel feature, but is there any workaround for it on the SSRS end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an Excel issue, not a Reporting Services one. The SSRS CSV export should contain the number as it exists in the report, e.g. 672000000000000

The default behaviour for Excel (which you are presumably using to open the CSV file) is to display values this large using scientific notation, i.e. "6.72E+14". This behaviour can't be controlled from within SSRS.

As an alternative you might consider using the **Excel** render method for the report, which might give you more control over the display of these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Excel won't mess with it if you convert the expression to a string within SSRS.
Go into the expression for the text box and type the following:
=Str(Fields!***YourFieldHere***.Value)